# Have there been any studies on how long COVID-19 remains infectious on various types of cloth?

Tags: covid-19, infectious-diseases, clothes

I was thinking common items like wool and cotton clothing. Has any one  discovered yet how long COVID-19 remains infectious on clothing?  I have seen the usual items such as paper boxs, stainless steel and plastic. Almost all my searches get hits on these but it ends there.

Clothing remains illusive thus far.

Comment: Probably not studied directly, but it has been mentioned by analogy in some articles ([NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/04/17/well/live/coronavirus-contagion-spead-clothes-shoes-hair-newspaper-packages-mail-infectious.html)): "Should I change my clothes and shower when I come home from the grocery store? For most of us who are practicing social distancing and making only occasional trips to the grocery store or pharmacy, experts agree that it’s not necessary to change clothes or take a shower when you return home. [...]"

Comment: "Studies show that some small viral particles could float in the air for about half an hour, but they don’t swarm like gnats and are unlikely to collide with your clothes. “A droplet that is small enough to float in air for a while also is unlikely to deposit on clothing because of aerodynamics,” said Linsey Marr, an aerosol scientist at Virginia Tech. “The droplets are small enough that they’ll move in the air around your body and clothing.”"

Comment: "Someone would have to spray large droplets through talking — a spit talker — coughing or sneezing for them to land on our clothes. The droplets have to be large enough that they don’t follow the streamlines.” So, if you’re out shopping and somebody sneezes on you, you probably do want to go home, change and shower. But the rest of the time, take comfort that your slow-moving body is pushing air and viral particles away from your clothes, a result of simple physics."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This study looked at various surfaces including cloth which was not otherwise specified.  They stated it lasted 2 days.  Other studies have said 3 days for plastics so if you have natural or synthetic clothing, then in the circumstances that the study looked at ( 65% humidity and ambient temperature of 22C ), you can expect 2-3 days on clothing.

> We further investigated the stability of this virus on different surfaces. Briefly, a 5 μL droplet of virus culture (∼7·8 log unit of TCID50 per mL) was pipetted on a surface (appendix p 1; ∼cm2 per piece) and left at room temperature (22°C) with a relative humidity of around 65%. The inoculated objects retrieved at desired time-points were immediately soaked with 200 μL of virus transport medium for 30 mins to elute the virus. Therefore, this recovery of virus **does not necessarily reflect the potential to pick up the virus from casual contact**. No infectious virus could be recovered from printing and tissue papers after a 3-hour incubation, whereas no infectious virus could be detected from treated wood and cloth on day 2.

Stability of SARS-CoV-2 in different environmental conditions
https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lanmic/article/PIIS2666-5247(20)30003-3/fulltext